# javascript Perl pack

Tags: javascript, perl, pack

First, I'll tell you
I cannot speak English, but I want to try and get information of how to implement a Perl pack into Javascript to make a node.js module.

To do that, I would like to get more information about the Perl pack. In particular, the information I  especially want to know "C, H *, N".

Also, if I could get more information on jspack, that would be wonderful.

Thank you in advance.

#### What I actually tried.

- [node-jspack](https://github.com/pgriess/node-jspack)

However, it didn't work.

[日本語(Japan)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34753/perl%E3%81%AEpack%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)

Comment: [perldoc -f pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)

Comment: There are tutorials especially designed to provide information about different languages and more, especially the documentation provided by the creators. SO is not a tutorial site, please try to ask something that many people can benefit from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pack 'C'`, `pack 'N'` and `pack 'H*'` are used to create a sequence of bytes.

```
my $bytes = pack('C', $uint8);

# Array of bytes
var bytes = [];
bytes.push(uint8);

# String of bytes
var bytes = "";
bytes += String.fromCharCode(uint8);
```

```
my $bytes = pack('N', $uint32);

# Array of bytes
var bytes = [];
bytes.push((uint32 >> 24) & 0xFF);
bytes.push((uint32 >> 16) & 0xFF);
bytes.push((uint32 >>  8) & 0xFF);
bytes.push((uint32      ) & 0xFF);

# String of bytes
var bytes = "";
bytes += String.fromCharCode((uint32 >> 24) & 0xFF);
bytes += String.fromCharCode((uint32 >> 16) & 0xFF);
bytes += String.fromCharCode((uint32 >>  8) & 0xFF);
bytes += String.fromCharCode((uint32      ) & 0xFF);
```

```
my $bytes = pack('H*', $hex_str);

# Array of bytes
function hexToBytes(hex) {
    var bytes = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < hex.length; c += 2)
       bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(c, 2), 16));

    return bytes;
}

# String of bytes
function hexToBytes(hex) {
    var bytes = "";
    for (var c = 0; c < hex.length; c += 2)
       bytes += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(c, 2), 16));

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Dunno what's going on these days, but upvoted to make up for that.

Comment: I tried to test the code in reference.Thanks to you, the problem has been solved. Thank you very much.  "test url":http://plnkr.co/urgQPFBQ76VSJyuqJy5f